# How do I intersect multiple secondary index queries

Tags: rethinkdb

If I have a table with multiple secondary indexes, how do I generate an intersection? For example, if I have a users table with secondary indexes on "firstName" and "lastName", and want all users named 'Bob Smith':

```
r.table('users').getAll('Bob', {index: 'firstName'}).XXXX('Smith', {index: 'lastName'})
```

I can use a filter, but my understanding is that would be slower:

```
r.table('users').getAll('Bob', {index: 'firstName'}).filter({'lastName': 'Smith'})
```

Alternatively, can I do intersections with a compound index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with a compound index. For example:

```
table.index_create("fullName", lambda doc: [doc["firstName"], doc["lastName"])
table.getAll(["Bob", "Smith"])
```

You can't currently use more than one index in a single query. It's something that Rethink might support in the future but right now it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the getAll should be getAll(["Bob", "Smith"], {index: 'fullName'})

Answer (score 0):

The correct updated way to do this is creating a compound secondary index based on the first_name and last_name attributes. Example updated in JS:

`r.table("users").indexCreate(
    "full_name", [r.row("last_name"), r.row("first_name")]
).run(conn, callback)`

Then your query will be something like Get all users whose last name is Smith and the first name  name is John.

`r.table("users").getAll(["Smith", "John"], {index: "full_name"}).run(conn, callback)`