# Creating compound index in rethink DB

Tags: rethinkdb, secondary-indexes, compound-index

I doing a query in rethink db,

```
r.db('main').table('log').distinct({index: 'number'}).between(r.epochTime((new Date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)/1000), r.epochTime((new Date).setHours(23, 59, 59, 99)/1000), {index: 'createdAt'}).count()
```

`number` and `createdAt` are two secondary indexess. Doing this will generate the error as We are not allowed to use multiple secondary indexes in single query. I've tried to create compound index using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656785/how-do-i-intersect-multiple-secondary-index-queries), but its different from my problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you describe some example data you would expect from this query? Since it's not valid, it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you look out into this -> https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/6184